# What code to add to CSS to get Firefox to read PNG images as having transparent backgrounds

Tags: css, png

I designed a website with a lot of PNG images.  All browsers except for Firefox display them properly.  Firefox doesn't read their background as transparent but puts ghost boxes around them.  Is there code that I can add to cause Firefox to properly display the PNG images?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "ghost boxes"? And are you sure the backgrounds are actually transparent and not just a super low percentage of a color?

Comment: I have seen firefox puts some black borders sometimes is that what you mean?

Comment: Which version of FF are you referring to?

Comment: Test your browser's ability to display transparent PNG files correctly: http://entropymine.com/jason/testbed/pngtrans

Answer (score 1):

If PNG's are displaying differently it's because you have Firefox set to display images using their embedded color profiles where your other browsers are not. In which case prodigitalson would be correct in that your images are not truly transparent.

A link to your page would be much more helpful though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using Firefox 3.6.13 (the latest version, I believe.) I checked preferences looking for a setting such as you describe but am not finding it.  The site is www.savethehorsesnow.org.  The "Events" page has a lot of them.

Comment: @Karen: With firefox 3.6.13 on a mac I see the PNGs fine, no borders, no backgrounds, transparent where they are transparent (for instance, the calendars at the end of the Events page).

Comment: The calendars are jpegs.  What about the heart on the Feb. calendar and the shamrock on March?  Those are pngs, and when I view them in Firefox they have boxes around them...not borders...it's the actual background of the png image (that's the shape).  I wish that I could attach a screen shot, but that's not possible, is it?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Firefox's ability to display images properly. This is some JavaScript that iWeb is inserting into your page (first step: stop using iWeb) to put those borders around your images. Firefox is putting the borders/shadows around your transparent PNG's which is why it looks like the image has a bounding box and giving you the impression the images have a different background.

Remove the JavaScript from your page (you don't need it) and style your image borders using CSS.

Comment: The images that I'm referencing don't have borders.  Is there a way for me to send you a screen shot?

Comment: The first link that I gave doesn't work, but the second one does.

Comment: You are seeing precisely what I, and everyone else are seeing. This is not an issue with Firefox or your PNG's. It's an issue with iWeb inserting JavaScript in your page that is adding those drop shadows AFTER the page has loaded. You can verify this by turning JavaScript off and reloading the page. Whatever issue you think you're having is nothing more than JavaScript placed by iWeb to give your images that odd drop-shadow in Firefox. Remove that JavaScript and all will be fine.

Comment: Thank you, Greg.  That did the trick.  I have posted this issue on several blogs over the last few weeks, and you are the only person who realized that it was the drop shadows.  Interesting that Firefox is the only browser that cannot read them correctly.  I also found that Firefox does the same thing on a jpeg IF I tilt the image.  Thanks again!